# Validating a form

Tags: javascript, css, html

IM working on a simple form, and Im trying to validate the fields, 
with below code I able to validate the field and add a message if the field is empty.
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript code to following:

```js
function validation(id) {
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
  if (value === "" || value == null) {
    document.getElementById('Err' + id).innerHTML = "- Field Required";
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('class');
    var label = findLabel(document.getElementById('Name'));
    label.classList.add('class');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Err' + id).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('class');
    var label = findLabel(document.getElementById('Name'));
    label.classList.remove('class');
  }
}

function findLabel(el) {
  var idVal = el.id;
  labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].htmlFor == idVal)
      return labels[i];
  }
}
```

```css
.class
{
    background: #f97d7d;
    color: #ff0000;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<label class="" for="Name">* Name <span class="error" id="ErrName"></span></label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" onblur="validation('Name')">
```

I've added a function `findLable` to get the label for that input, and using that, added error class to that label.

Comment: You have defined `findLable` but called `findLableForControl`. Please correct the name of the method defined/called.

Comment: Sorry about that, corrected both the above errors. Thanks for pointing them out :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to scan the page for labels:

```
  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].htmlFor != '') {
      var elem = document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor);
      if (elem)
        elem.label = labels[i];
    }
  }
```

Then you can simply use following in your IF-ELSE condition,

```
document.getElementById(id).label.classList.add('red-text');
```

and

```
document.getElementById(id).label.classList.remove('red-text');
```

I also added CSS class for the text to be red.

```
.red-text {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Final code:

```js
function validation(id) {
  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].htmlFor != '') {
      var elem = document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor);
      if (elem)
        elem.label = labels[i];
    }
  }
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
  if (value === "" || value == null) {
    document.getElementById('Err' + id).innerHTML = "- Field Required";
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('class');
    document.getElementById(id).label.classList.add('red-text');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Err' + id).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('class');
    document.getElementById(id).label.classList.remove('red-text');
  }
}
```

```css
.class {
  background: #f97d7d;
  color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}

.red-text {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<label for="Name">* Name <span class="error" id="ErrName"></span></label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" onblur="validation('Name')">
```

Answer (score 0):

The span is defined as class "error" but you haven't defined that class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to bind blur and input events

the code:

```
Name.addEventListener('blur', function(){
  if (!Name.value){
    ErrName.innerHTML="Field Required";
    this.classList.add('class');
    ErrName.parentNode.style.color="red";
  }
});

Name.addEventListener('input',function(){
  if (Name.value.length && ErrName.innerHTML=="Field Required" ){
    ErrName.innerHTML="";
    this.classList.remove('class');
    ErrName.parentNode.style.color="black";
  }
});
```

[a liddle fiddle](https://jsbin.com/lisaqorayi/edit?html,css,js,console,output)